# Configure button to remove image from imageUploader

Tags: image, adminform, delete, remove, field

Good morning, could someone help me configure the button to delete image from the imageUploader field, the image uploads it without problem, but when I press the delete button, the entry is clean, but the image that uploads is not deleted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it core Magento or Your custom uploader? Is this menu built in XML? Is it a UI component? Seems like You want to conditionally disable elements. Maybe this would be helpful:

https://karnowka.com/posts/magento2-conditional-layout-directives/

It all depends on how You build the buttons. Every XML has an XSD schema, which means each one has different possibilities but only a few allow to conditionally hide elements.

Maybe You can use:

```
<item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">hidden</item>
```

or disable elements in XML.

Anyway if it's adminhtml I would start looking at xmls.